# Conflicting descriptions of __bridge_transfer; does it avoid a double retain?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

Mike Ash says:

> When __bridge_transfer is used in a cast, it tells ARC that this object is already retained, and that ARC doesn't need to retain it again. Since ARC takes ownership, it will still release it when it's done.

Clang documentation says:

> (__bridge_transfer T) op casts the operand, which must have non-retainable pointer type, to the destination type, which must be a retainable object pointer type. ARC will release the value at the end of the enclosing full-expression, subject to the usual optimizations on local values.

Nowhere in the Clang documentation does it say that __bridge_transfer avoids a double retain. It only says that the object is released sometime in the future.

Why does this matter? Consider the following code snippet:

```
NSString *value = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFPreferencesCopyAppValue(CFSTR("someKey"), CFSTR("com.company.someapp"));
```

The CFStringRef starts out with a retainCount of +1. When it is assigned to value, the CFStringRef is retained again because, by default, `value` is strongly referenced. This results in a double retain. At the end of the scope, a -release is sent to `value`, but nothing else exists to balance the lingering retain from CFPreferences**Copy**AppValue, resulting in a memory leak.

How does `__bridge_transfer` avoid a double retain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang's documentation agrees with Mike Ash. It says it performs a cast, and the object is released at the end of the scope. There is no retain performed during the cast.

Basically, `(__bridge_transfer T)` causes the value to be treated as an already-owned value of type `T`, just as how calling `[T new]` would return an already-owned value of type `T`.

Comment: Clang's documentation does not say in any way that "when __bridge_transfer is used in a cast, it tells ARC that this object is already retained, and that ARC doesn't need to retain it again". This implies that there exists some built in intelligence where ARC recognizes that we're about to assign to a strongly referenced type and subsequently eats up a -retain message to avoid a double retain. Is this correct?

Comment: To add on to that, yes, I agree that no retain is performed on the cast. But there is a retain that occurs during the assignment to `value`.

Comment: @nessup: I should clarify: The Clang documentation explicitly states the value will be released at the end of the full-expression. This basically means "this is an owned value". There is no retain during the cast, but there is a release after. Assigning to the local variable will subsequently retain a second time, but there will also be a second release when that variable goes out of scope. And the optimizer will recognize the double-retain and remove it, so you'll be left with a single retain (and a single release at the end of the scope).

Answer (score 0):

When you use "transfer", ARC decrements the objects retain count at the end of what its doing - so in this case, you started with a count of 1, "value" is strong so it increments the count, but the "transfer" causes a decrement so you end up back with 1.

```
NSString *value = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFStringCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 1000, CFSTR("Hello World") );
NSLog(@"value retainCount %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)value));
NSLog(@"Value = %@", value);
```

2012-07-23 17:45:49.421 TimeTester[75918:f803] value retainCount 1
2012-07-23 17:45:49.423 TimeTester[75918:f803] Value = Hello World

Comment: Your description of the behavior of what actually happens is absolutely correct. It seems to me, then, that Mike Ash's recommendation actually causes a memory leak because nothing exists to balance the +1 from CreateMutablyCopy...

Comment: Check out http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html . Cmd+F for "The __bridge_transfer annotation solves this problem".